# Bluetooth Raw Advertisement Data

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm using flutter_reactive_ble to access Bluetooth. However, it only returns spesified data like mac address, name, service data etc. I need the whole raw advertisement data. Is there a way I can access this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a solution to get the raw advertisement data. I used the manufacturer-specific data to place my data. You can then get it by calling `device.manufacturerData`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).